# Jasper Sum isn't including the last value

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using Jaspersoft Studio 5.6.2 and have a report with a column showing elapsed days between two dates.

I want to show at least one day if the date range is less than 24 hours so I created a variable to convert the field value to indicate that.  I also want to avoid negative values:

```
Name: day_rounded
Class: java.lang.Integer
Calculation: No Calculation
Expression: $F{days}==0?1:$F{days}<0?0:$F{days}
Increment: None
Reset: Report
```

Here is the variable I created to total them:

```
Name: totals
Class: java.lang.Integer
Calculation: Sum
Expression: $V{day_rounded}
Increment: None
Reset: Report
```

$F{days} is the difference between two dates from the query.

```
...
DATEDIFF(dd,irr.xxxstart_dt, ISNULL(irr.xxxend_dt,$P{end_dt})) AS days
...
```

I ran the report with the $F{days} value alongside the $V{day_rounded} value and they look OK.

When i put the $V{totals} into the Summary band (it is in the Page Header as well) the value does not include the one on the last row.   For instance if I use a calculator and sum up all the days listed I get 1494.   The report shows 1485 and the *days* value for the last row is 9 - so I can see it is not including that one.  I ran the report for other date ranges and the total always is exactly the value in the last row less than it should be.

As far as I can tell the variables are declared correctly.  Any idea why I am missing the final row value in the sum?

Comment: How does the report generally look like? Is there a details band you use?

Comment: Yes, I have a page header with the column titles in the master and the subreport runs by itself in the detail band.  As noted I put the total in the Summary - but I also tried it in the page header as an experiment and it showed the same value.  I tried changing the evaluation time to all possible options but it never picked up the last row.   Although....I wonder if I could set it to Page, then use another variable which sums all the page totals with an eval time set to Report??  Assuming it picked up all the rows along the way.  I suppose it couldn't hurt.   I am going to try that on Monday.

Comment: If it doesn't work, please [edit] your question and add some details like the jrxml source code and screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the jrxml I used to solve this:

```
    <variable name="page_total" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Page" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{day_rounded}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="paged_summed" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Page" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{page_total}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

I totaled my days values per page and had the RESET set to 'Page' for that variable.  I summed them up and set the INCREMENT to 'Page for the other variable.

Now my totals are all adding up.  Thank you @tobi6!!

Comment: No worries, glad to help.